# is it possible to use 2 diffrent liberies when each one of them depends on diffrent version of protobuf?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, cld3

in my JVM based project, I am loading 2 different libraries

1) [CLD3](https://github.com/ntedgi/cld3-kotlin) that uses **protobuffer 3.8** and cannot be compiled otherwise

[image]

2) [libtensorflow - 1.13.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/libtensorflow) that uses **protobuffer 3.7.1**

that's throw error depending on who is loaded first

is there any way to solve this dependencies issue

**if compiling with the same protobuffer version is not an option?**

i forked tensorflow master branch , they add 5 days ago support for protobufffer 3.8 in this commit

https://github.com/ntedgi/tensorflow/commit/508f76b1d9925304cedd56d51480ec380636cb82

but its isn't a stable version and I really **don't want to maintain this fork or wait until a new release**

Comment: Is this in the same process? Or via IPC/RPC? The latter should be fine (the binary format doesn't change between versions). The former is more complex.

Comment: the same process :-(